Dataframe set all in group with value that occurs first in corresponding multi columns
I have multiple A* columns with corresponding B* columns (A and B have the corresponding numbers at the end of the column names).
When the REFNO value = A# value and the 'MNGR' is not BOB, I need to put the value from corresponding B# column into the ‘AGE’ column and the corresponding # number in the 'FLAG' column.
The next step is to set the same AGE and FLAG values that occurred first in the group to all employees in that group (group by MNGR, YEAR).
The A* and B* columns can be more than 10 columns.
But I got this error:
Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (8, 2).
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'EMPLID': [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    'MNGR': ['BOB', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA', 'JIM', 'RHONDA', 'RHONDA', 'BOB'],
    'YEAR': [2012, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2012, 2012],
    'REFNO': [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2],
    'A1': [1,3,2,4,5,4,3,1],
    'A2': [2,4,4,5,7,5,4,2],
    'A3': [3,5,8,6,8,6,5,3],
    'B1': [21,31,41,44,51,61,71,81],
    'B2': [22,32,42,45,52,62,72,82],
    'B3': [23,33,43,46,53,63,73,83]
    })

for i in(1,3):     
    df['AGE', 'FLAG'] = df.loc[(df['REFNO'] == df[f'A{i}']) & (df['MNGR'] != 'BOB'), 
                               [f'B{i}','i']]

df2 = df.groupby(['MNGR', 'YEAR']).first()

The next step is to fill every record in the group with the same AGE and FLAG that occurs first (this can be done by regular merging of df and df2).
Expected output:
   EMPLID    MNGR  YEAR  REFNO  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  AGE  FLAG
0      12     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  21  22  23   0   0
1      13     JIM  2013      3   3   4   5  31  32  33  31   1
2      14  RHONDA  2012      4   2   4   8  41  42  43  42   2
3      15  RHONDA  2012      4   4   5   6  44  45  46  42   2
4      16     JIM  2012      5   5   7   8  51  52  53  51   1
5      17  RHONDA  2013      6   4   5   6  61  62  63  63   3
6      18  RHONDA  2012      4   3   4   5  71  72  73  42   2
7      19     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  81  82  83  0    0


Try to use df2 = df.groupby(['MNGR', 'YEAR'])[['AGE', 'FLAG']].transform('first'). Then merge back the AGE And FLAG into the original data frame. Hope that helps you.

Without the need for a loop:
m = df.filter(regex=r'^A\d').eq(df['REFNO'], axis=0).values

df['AGE'] = df.filter(regex=r'^B\d').where(m).max(axis=1).astype(int)
df['FLAG'] = m.argmax(axis=1) + 1

df[['AGE', 'FLAG']] = (df.groupby(['MNGR', 'YEAR'])[['AGE', 'FLAG']]
                       .transform('first')
                       .where(df['MNGR'].ne('BOB'),
                              0)
                       )

Output:
   EMPLID    MNGR  YEAR  REFNO  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  AGE  FLAG
0      12     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  21  22  23    0     0
1      13     JIM  2013      3   3   4   5  31  32  33   31     1
2      14  RHONDA  2012      4   2   4   8  41  42  43   42     2
3      15  RHONDA  2012      4   4   5   6  44  45  46   42     2
4      16     JIM  2012      5   5   7   8  51  52  53   51     1
5      17  RHONDA  2013      6   4   5   6  61  62  63   63     3
6      18  RHONDA  2012      4   3   4   5  71  72  73   42     2
7      19     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  81  82  83    0     0

Explanation / Intermediates

Create an np.ndarray boolean mask (m), comparing all 'A' columns with 'REFNO' using df.filter + df.eq on axis=0 + df.values.

# m

array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]])


For 'AGE', take all 'B' columns and keep only the values where m is True (df.where), extracting them per row with df.max on axis=1. (Add Series.astype to restore integers.)

# df.filter(regex=r'^B\d').where(m)

     B1    B2    B3
0   NaN  22.0   NaN # < extract `22.0` with max for `'AGE'`
1  31.0   NaN   NaN # < extract `31.0` with max for `'AGE'`
2   NaN  42.0   NaN
3  44.0   NaN   NaN 
4  51.0   NaN   NaN
5   NaN   NaN  63.0
6   NaN  72.0   NaN
7   NaN  82.0   NaN


For 'FLAG', apply ndarray.argmax to m on axis=1 to get indices for True, adding 1 since indices will start at 0.
Finally, use df.groupby on ['MNGR', 'YEAR'] + groupby.transform + groupby.first to propagate first matches for all duplicates, then applying df.where to reset rows for df['MNGR'] == "BOB" to 0.

N.B. The above method assumes that both your 'A' and 'B' columns are ordered (i.e. ['A1', 'A2', ...] and ['B1', 'B2', ...]).

I learned a lot from the all the different solutions, but I chose this one because it provided a technique without using for loop that is new to me.  I also really appreciate the step-by-step explanations.

What I have done here is handle the AGE and FLAG propagation within groups defined by MNGR and YEAR
Code is tested
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "EMPLID": [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        "MNGR": ["BOB", "JIM", "RHONDA", "RHONDA", "JIM", "RHONDA", "RHONDA", "BOB"],
        "YEAR": [2012, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2012, 2012],
        "REFNO": [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2],
        "A1": [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1],
        "A2": [2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 2],
        "A3": [3, 5, 8, 6, 8, 6, 5, 3],
        "B1": [21, 31, 41, 44, 51, 61, 71, 81],
        "B2": [22, 32, 42, 45, 52, 62, 72, 82],
        "B3": [23, 33, 43, 46, 53, 63, 73, 83],
    }
)

# Initialize AGE and FLAG columns
df["AGE"] = 0
df["FLAG"] = 0

# Update AGE and FLAG columns based on conditions
for i in range(1, 4):  # Adjust range if more columns
    a_col = f"A{i}"
    b_col = f"B{i}"

    # Set AGE and FLAG based on conditions
    mask = (df["MNGR"] != "BOB") & (df["REFNO"] == df[a_col])
    df.loc[mask, "AGE"] = df.loc[mask, b_col]
    df.loc[mask, "FLAG"] = i

# Group by MNGR and YEAR, then fill AGE and FLAG based on the first occurrence in each group
df_grouped = df.groupby(["MNGR", "YEAR"], as_index=False).first()

# Merge back to fill AGE and FLAG for all records within the same group
df = df.merge(
    df_grouped[["MNGR", "YEAR", "AGE", "FLAG"]],
    on=["MNGR", "YEAR"],
    how="left",
    validate="many_to_one",
    suffixes=("", "_first"),
)

# Drop redundant columns and rename as needed
df = df.drop(["AGE", "FLAG"], axis=1)
df.rename(columns={"AGE_first": "AGE", "FLAG_first": "FLAG"}, inplace=True)

print(df)



Your desired result.
 ☞ python3 s.py
   EMPLID    MNGR  YEAR  REFNO  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  AGE  FLAG
0      12     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  21  22  23    0     0
1      13     JIM  2013      3   3   4   5  31  32  33   31     1
2      14  RHONDA  2012      4   2   4   8  41  42  43   42     2
3      15  RHONDA  2012      4   4   5   6  44  45  46   42     2
4      16     JIM  2012      5   5   7   8  51  52  53   51     1
5      17  RHONDA  2013      6   4   5   6  61  62  63   63     3
6      18  RHONDA  2012      4   3   4   5  71  72  73   42     2
7      19     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  81  82  83    0     0  



Iterate over the numbers from columns 'A#' and update columns 'AGE' and 'FLAG' accordingly, the use groupby and transform with 'first'
df[["AGE", "FLAG"]] = 0

n = df.filter(regex=r"^A\d").columns.str.extract(r"(\d+)").astype(int)[0].tolist()
exclude_mngr = ["BOB"]

for i in n:
    m = (df["REFNO"] == df[f"A{i}"]) & (~df["MNGR"].isin(exclude_mngr))
    df.loc[m, "AGE"] = df[f"B{i}"]
    df.loc[m, "FLAG"] = i

df[["AGE", "FLAG"]] = df.groupby(["MNGR", "YEAR"])[["AGE", "FLAG"]].transform("first")

   EMPLID    MNGR  YEAR  REFNO  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  AGE  FLAG
0      12     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  21  22  23    0     0
1      13     JIM  2013      3   3   4   5  31  32  33   31     1
2      14  RHONDA  2012      4   2   4   8  41  42  43   42     2
3      15  RHONDA  2012      4   4   5   6  44  45  46   42     2
4      16     JIM  2012      5   5   7   8  51  52  53   51     1
5      17  RHONDA  2013      6   4   5   6  61  62  63   63     3
6      18  RHONDA  2012      4   3   4   5  71  72  73   42     2
7      19     BOB  2012      2   1   2   3  81  82  83    0     0

